# Why is it pushing the parameter name and not the element? JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, sorting, object

**Info:** I'm sorting an array of names into two arrays, one has names starting with A-M, N-Z in the other. I want each entry to be an object with the name as the property and an empty string as the value, like this --> {'Name' : ' '}  but instead all of the entries are like this --> {val: ' '}

This is how I'm pushing entries --> arrAM.push({val: ' '});

**Question:**  How do I need to modify ^^^^ this method to get the Name in there instead of val.  Thanks for any help!

```
var separate = function(array){
  var arrAM = [];
  var arrNZ = [];
  _.each(array, function(val){

    if (/^[a-m]/i.test(val)){
        arrAM.push({val: ''});
    }
    else{
        arrNZ.push({val: ''})
    }
})
return arrAM;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ES6 has a syntactic sugar for [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#Computed_property_names) in object initializers:

```
arrAM.push({[val]: ''});
```

Pre-ES6 requires you to use bracket syntax in a separate statement:

```
var obj = {};
obj[val] = '';
arrAM.push(obj);
```